# error while compiling u-boot

Tags: android, linux, compilation, u-boot

I am trying to build u-boot and getting these error

```
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE G0
Building U-boot
make -C u-boot ARCH=arm fio-om3xxx_config
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mrigendra/GingerBread_2_3_4_FIO/u-boot'
Configuring for fio-om3xxx board...
rm: cannot remove `asm': Is a directory
make[1]: *** [fio-om3xxx_config] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mrigendra/GingerBread_2_3_4_FIO/u-boot'
make: *** [uboot] Error 2
```

i don't know why it wants to remove asm directory.
do anybody have idea from where i should start ..

Comment: What is you **PATH** variable?  What version of U-Boot are you trying to build?

Comment: actually this problem is solved, there was some problem with path variable. but a new problem came as cannot find lgcc